# Method level resource(ex:FileInputStream,Connection) not closed, will the object be eligible for garbage collection and will the resource get closed?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, resources, garbage-collection

1. I have a file named abc.txt.
2. I made a connection to it by:

   FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
3. This resides in method level.
4. If I don't close the connection, will the object be eligible for garbage collection?
5. Will the resource be closed?

Program Example:

```
class Hello {
public void readFile(){
 FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
/* 
here i wont close the connection

*/
}

}
class Demo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
 Hello h = Hello();
  h.readFile();
/*
Some other operation
*/
}
}
```

Scenario 2: In main method i dereference the h.

```
class Demo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   Hello h = Hello();
   h.readFile();
   h = null;//Dereference
  }
}
```

Now is this h object eligible for garbage collection. (Note: the resource connection is not closed)

Comment: General rule of thumb, if you open, you must close it. There's no way to 100% sure if the resource will be closed, as the resource may contain references to other objects which aren't eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Native resources - i.e. anything accessing things outside the java heap, such as file handles of the underlying operating system - is usually subject to manual resource management, i.e. it has to be closed/deallocated.

Some classes auto-close on object finalization, *but that is very unreliable since on large heaps finalization can be postponed to an indefinite point in the future*.
  So you really shouldn't rely on that anyway since it consumes resource for an unpredictable amount of time.

Other classes might keep the resource allocated until the VM exits. Some cleanups may not happen at all under some circumstances, e.g. tempfiles may not get deleted if the VM does not exit cleanly.

If in doubt, [read the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#finalize%28%29) of the class in question.

In your particular toy example the VM exit is likely to occur before garbage collection kicks in.

You should generally use [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements for input streams.